# Pandas cumulative conditional sum by dates

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine a pandas DataFrame like this

```
      date  id  initial_value  part_value
2016-01-21   1            100          10
2016-05-18   1            100          20
2016-03-15   2            150          75
2016-07-28   2            150          50
2016-08-30   2            150          25
2015-07-21   3             75          75
```

Generated with following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': (1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3),
    'date': tuple(pd.to_datetime(date) for date in
                  ('2016-01-21', '2016-05-18', '2016-03-15', '2016-07-28', '2016-08-30', '2015-07-21')),
    'initial_value': (100, 100, 150, 150, 150, 75),
    'part_value': (10, 20, 75, 50, 25, 75)}).sort_values(['id', 'date'])
```

I wish to add a column with the remaining value defined by the `initial_value` minus the cumulative sum of `part_value` conditioned on id and dates before. Hence I wish my goal is

```
      date  id  initial_value  part_value  goal
2016-01-21   1            100          10   100
2016-05-18   1            100          20    90
2016-03-15   2            150          75   150
2016-07-28   2            150          50    75
2016-08-30   2            150          25    25
2015-07-21   3             75          75    75
```

I'm thinking that a solution can be made by combining the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159490/pandas-cumulative-sum-of-one-column-based-on-value-of-another) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601017/pandas-conditional-cumulative-sum), but I can't exactly figure it out.

Comment: Can you explain more `dates before` ? If dates are not sorted, output is different?

Comment: you understood correctly. Sorting matters

Comment: Ok, so is necessary sort values first? Or values are sorted?

Comment: I've sorted them when creating the example so they can be assumed sorted. Easy to sort nevertheless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If dont use `dates` values need [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html), [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) and `groupby` with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df['goal'] = df.initial_value.add(df.part_value).sub(df.groupby('id').part_value.cumsum())
print (df)
        date  id  initial_value  part_value  goal
0 2016-01-21   1            100          10   100
1 2016-05-18   1            100          20    90
2 2016-03-15   2            150          75   150
3 2016-07-28   2            150          50    75
4 2016-08-30   2            150          25    25
5 2015-07-21   3             75          75    75
```

What is same as:

```
df['goal'] = df.initial_value + df.part_value - df.groupby('id').part_value.cumsum()
print (df)
        date  id  initial_value  part_value  goal
0 2016-01-21   1            100          10   100
1 2016-05-18   1            100          20    90
2 2016-03-15   2            150          75   150
3 2016-07-28   2            150          50    75
4 2016-08-30   2            150          25    25
5 2015-07-21   3             75          75    75
```

Comment: Or even: `(df.initial_value - df.groupby('id').part_value.shift(1).fillna(0)).astype(int)` ?

Comment: Yes, there is problem with values in 4 index - `100` instead `25`

Answer (score 0):

I actually came up with a solution myself as well. I guess it is kind of the same that is happening.

```
df['goal'] = df.initial_value - ((df.part_value).groupby(df.id).cumsum() - df.part_value)
df
        date  id  initial_value  part_value  goal
0 2016-01-21   1            100          10   100
1 2016-05-18   1            100          20    90
2 2016-03-15   2            150          75   150
3 2016-07-28   2            150          50    75
4 2016-08-30   2            150          25    25
5 2015-07-21   3             75          75    75
```